# Using Lodash to loop through https.get when parsing XML to JSON in Node

Tags: json, xml, node.js, lodash

I'm trying to parse XML to JSON in Node. I'm using xml2js. I'd like to incorporate Lodash to loop through each number in an array and use the corresponding url to convert the XML to JSON. When I use the code below, I get a `Non-whitespace before first tag` error. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

```
const no = [78787878,78787879, 787878780];

_.forEach(no, https.get('https://tsdrapi.uspto.gov/ts/cd/casestatus/'+no+'/info.xml', function (res) {
    res.on('data', function (chunk) {
        response_data += chunk;
    });
    res.on('end', function () {
        parser.parseString(response_data, function (err, result) {
            if (err) {
                console.log('Got error: ' + err.message);
            } else {
                console.log(util.inspect(result, false, null));
            }
        });
    });
    res.on('error', function (err) {
        console.log('Got error: ' + err.message);
    });
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

Honestly the `forEach` helper in LoDash is kind of silly. `forEach` is a prototype method of any `Array` instance. One problem is that these functional helpers are not designed to handle async flow control.

While there are a dozen ways to handle flow control the easiest would probably be to use `caolan/async` module's `map()` method.

You're code would look something like:

```
var no = [78787878,78787879, 787878780];

async.map(no, function(cb) {
    https.get('https://tsdrapi.uspto.gov/ts/cd/casestatus/'+no+'/info.xml', function (res) {
        var response_data = '';
        res.on('data', function (chunk) {
            response_data += chunk;
        });
        res.on('end', function () {
            parser.parseString(response_data, function (err, result) {
                if (err) {
                    cb(err);
                } else {
                    cb(null, result);
                }
            });
        });
        res.on('error', cb);
    })
}, function(err, results) {
    if(err) {
        console.log("Error occured: ", err);
    }
    else {
        console.log("Results(array): ", results);
    }
});
```

The difference here is that async maps the array to a function with a callback. This way you can gather the response from each request into an array and fire a callback when each request has responded. If one of them error's out the process stops and fires the final callback where the error is logged(or you can write logic to handle another way).